# Manipulating the JSON column and split the values

Tags: json, postgresql

I have the following text in one of my Postgres table as TEXT datatype:

```
[
 {"type": "text", "values": ["General"], "valueType": "string", "fieldType": "text", "value": ["General"], "customFieldId": "ee", "name": "customer_group"}, 
 {"type": "text", "values": ["Vienna"], "valueType": "string", "fieldType": "text", "value": ["Vienna"], "customFieldId": "eU", "name": "customer_city"},
 {"type": "text", "values": ["Mario"], "valueType": "string", "fieldType": "text", "value": ["Mario"], "customFieldId": "eZ", "name": "first_name"},
 {"type": "text", "values": ["2019-06-30"], "valueType": "date", "fieldType": "text", "value": ["2019-06-30"], "customFieldId": "ea", "name": "created_at_date"}
]
```

I need to split the values of this TEXT field to columns and rows. For that I have converted the TEXT column to JSON as below:

```
SELECT CAST( "customFieldValues" as JSON) "customFieldValues" FROM fr.contacts
```

But when I tried to manipulate this JSON value I'm getting NULL as result.

```
WITH  CTE AS(SELECT CAST( "customFieldValues" as JSON) "customFieldValues" FROM fr.contacts
)
 SELECT
   "customFieldValues" ->>'customer_city' as dd
 FROM CTE
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on this? How to get the column names and it's values in rows. I want to create a TABLE based on this data.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

below is the expected result,

```
customer_group   customer_city     first_name       created_at_date
General          Vienna            Mario            2019-06-30
```

Comment: There is no such element as 'sending_status_update'. Of course this gives NULL. Please show us the expected result.

Comment: @S-Man Thanks a lot for the swift response! I have edited the code to the correct element(I have copied only a part of the code here and the column sending_status_update is there in the original code), But even if i give the existing code it is showing as NULL. Will post the sample result set.

Comment: ... you change the query code into customer_city. But in you example this element does not exist as well... Please work more precisely.

Comment: @S-Man  The second line of the sample JSON string which i mentioned above contains  the customer_city , This is the column name and the value is "".........{"type": "text", "values": ["Vienna"], "valueType": "string", "fieldType": "text", "value": ["Spaichingen"], "customFieldId": "eU", "name": "customer_city"},

Comment: @S-Man "name": "customer_city", That is existing right? or Can you correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: Ah I see. The ->> operator takes the key, not the value. That's why I missed it.

Comment: @S-Man So can you please let me know how this resul set can be achieved?

Comment: It's still confusing. Why is the value always two times? Why is there one "Mario" and one "Marion". Where comes "Spaichingen" from? Why is values an array?

Comment: I surely can help. But you need to clarify your input.

Comment: @S-Man Really sorry for the confusion, The above string is a TEXT and i want to separate it's values to rows and columns in the above format, So thought of converting it to a JSON and manipulate it using the JSON operators,That's what came into my mind.  Also there are value and values field but the values in both are exactly same, I have edited few values in the output and missed to edit some, Now i have corrected the values.

Comment: @S-Man Is there anyway to achieve this result set? Kindly note that the datatype of the column is TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: It is still not clear:

- Why is there one element `values` and one `value`? What is the difference?
- Why are these elements arrays?

---

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2e52d02d0d5c5eae84944b56e64692af)

```
SELECT 
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE column_name = 'customer_group') AS customer_group,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE column_name = 'customer_city') AS customer_city,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE column_name = 'first_name') AS first_name,
    MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE column_name = 'created_at_date') AS created_at_date
FROM (
    SELECT
        elems ->> 'name' AS column_name,
        elems -> 'value' ->> 0 AS value,
        data
    FROM
        mytable,
        json_array_elements(data::json) elems
) s
GROUP BY data
```

1. Cast text to json with `::json`
2. Expand the JSON array: One row for each element with `json_array_elements()`
3. Getting the value: `-> 'value'` gets the array, `->> 0` gets the text representation of the first array element (the only one here)
4. Getting the column: `->> 'name'` gets the text representation of the column name
5. Classical pivot algorithm (turning rows to columns) with the `FILTER` clause.